# How to change validation on a Formfield depending on other Formfields?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

The Goal is to implement a Form, which inputfields are only required if one or more of the inputfields is filled out. If none of the fields is filled out, no field should be required. It was suggested on a website, that i should use "valueChanges" to make a listener on the fields and then implement the logic inside the listener. Then after the logic inside the listener I call the method "updateValueAndValidity()".
Now here occurs the problem. If I include "updateValueAndValidity()" I get the error:
[Recursion Error in the Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7xwz.png). I don't really understand why I get a Recursion error on this one, because I don't see where I have recursion. Probably "updateValueAndValidity()" triggers my listener again.

If I don't include "updateValueAndValidity()" I don't get the recursion error, but the logic doesn't work. I have no idea how to solve this, can someone help me?

```
isFormEmtpy: boolean = true;
lieferadresseForm: FormGroup;
   
onChanges() {
        let street = this.lieferadresseForm.get('street');
        let streetNumber = this.lieferadresseForm.get('streetNumber');
        let zipCode = this.lieferadresseForm.get('zipCode');
    
        this.lieferadresseForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
          console.log(val);
          this.isFormEmtpy = true;
          if(val.street !== '') {
            this.isFormEmtpy = false;
          } else if(val.streetNumber !== '') {
            this.isFormEmtpy = false;
          } else if(val.zipCode !== '') {
            this.isFormEmtpy = false;
          }
    
          if(this.isFormEmtpy == false) {
            street.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(36)]);
            streetNumber.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)]);
            zipCode.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)]);
          } else {
            street.setValidators([Validators.maxLength(36)]);
            streetNumber.setValidators([Validators.maxLength(10)]);
            zipCode.setValidators([Validators.maxLength(10)]);
          }

          strasse.updateValueAndValidity();
          hausnummer.updateValueAndValidity();
          postleitzahl.updateValueAndValidity();
            
        });
      }
    
      ngOnInit() {
        this.lieferadresseForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          street: ['', Validators.maxLength(36)],
          streetNumber: ['', Validators.maxLength(10)],
          zipCode: ['', Validators.maxLength(10)]
        });
            
        this.onChanges();
    }
```

Comment: make a custom validator of the FormGroup. Really it's more simple and robust that use setValidators , see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass **{emitEvent:false}** object configuration to updateValueAndValidity method to stop triggering valueChanges observables.

**Try this:**

```
onChanges() {
        let street = this.lieferadresseForm.get('street');
        let streetNumber = this.lieferadresseForm.get('streetNumber');
        let zipCode = this.lieferadresseForm.get('zipCode');
    
        this.lieferadresseForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
          console.log(val);
          this.isFormEmtpy = true;
          if(val.street !== '') {
            this.isFormEmtpy = false;
          } else if(val.streetNumber !== '') {
            this.isFormEmtpy = false;
          } else if(val.zipCode !== '') {
            this.isFormEmtpy = false;
          }
    
          if(this.isFormEmtpy == false) {
            street.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(36)]);
            streetNumber.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)]);
            zipCode.setValidators([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(10)]);
          } else {
            street.setValidators([Validators.maxLength(36)]);
            streetNumber.setValidators([Validators.maxLength(10)]);
            zipCode.setValidators([Validators.maxLength(10)]);
          }

          strasse.updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent:false});
          hausnummer.updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent:false});
          postleitzahl.updateValueAndValidity({emitEvent:false});
            
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `updateValueAndValidity()` on a formControl.

```
yourForm.controls['controlName'].updateValueAndValidity();
```

In your case it will be like

```
lieferadresseForm.controls['streetNumber']..updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: Hello HariHaran, thanks for the answer. I tried it, but still the same recursion error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are subscribing to the forms value changes into the onChange function.Basically you are subscribing to the forms change at every change detection cycle creating every time a new subscribtion and this leads to a huge memory leak.

Move the code you wrote into the ngOnInit function or at least a function that will be called just once.

In this case you don't need to handle the onChange lifecycle because you are listening to the form change itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's better create a custom formError of the formGroup. It's more simple than you think: Just create a function in your component:

```
   requiredIfOneNotEmpty()
    {
       return (formGroup:FormGroup)=>{
          const oneFilled=formGroup.value.street || 
                  formGroup.value.streetNumber || 
                  formGroup.value.zipCode
          if (!oneFilled)
              return null
          const error={}
          if (!formGroup.value.street)
              error.requiredStreet='Street is required';
          if (!formGroup.value.streetNumber )
              error.requiredStreetNumber='Street number is required'
          if (!formGroup.value.zipCode)
              error.requiredZipCode:'Zip code is required'

          return error
       }
    }
```

then you can simply create the form

```
formGroup=new FormGroup({
     street:new FormControl(null,Validators.maxLength(36)),
     streetNumber:new FormControl(null,Validators.maxLength(10)),
     zipCode:new FormControl(null,Validators.maxLength(10));
},this.requiredIfOneNotEmpty())
```

You check the error using

```
<div *ngIf="formGroup.errors?.requiredStreet">Required Street</div>
<div *ngIf="formGroup.errors?.requiredStreetNumber">Required Street Number</div>
<div *ngIf="formGroup.errors?.requiredZipCode">Required Zip Code</div>
```